# ASP.NET v4 MVC site deployed on IIS 8 Server 404 (Not Found) error on Javascript content generated by a 3rd Party dll

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-8

I've found numerous posts describing this problem but the solutions didn't help me. As described I had a working application on ISS Express, but when switching to Local IIS or deploying to a remote server I'm getting a 404 not found error.

1. I've ensured my AppPool is running as AppPoolIdentity and have given the pool Read/Execute credentials on the site folders.
2. I've tried both Anonymous login with IUSR credentials set to Read/Execute as well as Windows Authentication with Impersonation enabled.
3. I've added runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" to the web.config (the dll's are getting deployed with the site)
4. I've talked to the original creators of the dll's and had them whip up a working example on their system with the same libraries and send it over. I experienced the same issue as before when deployed, so I'm thinking it's an IIS configuration issue.

Browser Errors:

```
GET http://serverName:81/websiteName/Service/?Request=LS;Id=websiteName!EBR;Id=0!SCSS; net::ERR_ABORTED

GET http://serverName:81/websiteName/Service/?Request=SRT;AssemblyName=A.ThirdParty.Assembly|Path=A.ThirdParty.Assembly.MinifiedScript.js 404 (Not Found)
```

I also tried creating the 'Service' folder which turned those 404s into 403 Forbidden, even after giving write credentials to the AppPool (which I don't think I need to)

One of those four things was the solution to most of the posts I've read so far, but none have worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by creating a new site from scratch. Not sure what was causing this issue, could have been that I had the site in a subfolder of the IIS Website. 
Now that is no longer true, so I'm guessing the relative path is now working, whereas before it was not able to find the file being served.